# A strange character called NUL is randomly generated

Tags: javascript, macos, sublimetext3

I do JavaScript development on the Mac.
Mount the centos shared folder and modify and create the code files in that folder.

However, when you open a file in the same shared folder on your Mac, the following strange characters are generated.

I was wondering if it was an editor problem, so I switched to vscode and the same character was created.

So, it's okay to check the operating system problem, fix the code in Linux and open it in Windows. Of course, there was no problem in Windows.

As a result, I noticed that there was a difference in the Mac.

But I do not know the cause.

If anyone knows anyone, please ask me to solve it.

Mac-sierra).
[image]
Windows-10).
[image]

Comment: Possibly this is a known issue with Mac doing something wiggy with file shares. Switching to an NFS share or possibly changing the value of the `atomic_save` setting might help. See https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1332

Comment: @OdatNurd thank you! i solve it.